# Split .txt file and Append to Two Separate Lists Python

Tags: python, list, append, traversal

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

[image]

How could I traverse through each line of the text file, split the two string elements on the comma, and append each string element into its own list?

I have:

```
longSubjectNames = [] #example: "Academy for Classical Acting"
abbreviations = [] #example: "ACA"

with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.txt", "r") as myfile:
subjectAndAbrevs = tuple(open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.txt", 'r'))

for subAbrevsLine in subjectAndAbrevs:
   subAbrevsLine.strip()
   allSubsAndAbrevs = subAbrevsLine.split(",")
```

This isn't splitting the string elements correctly. Once the two string elements are split, how could I then append them to their respective lists?

Comment: Explain "isn't splitting the string elements correctly"(my guess is you still have trailing '\n' in second item)? Also as strings are immutable `subAbrevsLine.strip()` is useless. And why aren't you using `csv` module for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usings lists will not let you know if your file as more than one comma per a line, so I would use tuples instead, like such:

```
longSubjectNames = [] #example: "Academy for Classical Acting"
abbreviations = [] #example: "ACA"

with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.txt", "r") as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        name, abrev = line.replace("\n","").split(",")
        longSubjectNames.append(name)
        abbreviations.append(abrev)

print longSubjectNames
print abbreviations
```

Comment: @Snickers3192 Getting a "ValueError: too many values to unpack" with this.

Comment: this is because you must have more than one comma

Comment: @Snickers3192 there is only one comma per line throughout the entire .txt file.

Comment: who the hell edited the top remark of my question lol. Yeah I would use tuples as opposed to lists unlike the other answer as then you would not know that you have a problem with having more than one comma on a line. Variable names make it more readable too.

Comment: I would say you are mistaken with your assumption with the commas, I have tested my code myself. Why don't you test to see that this is the case.

Comment: @Snickers3192 I have tried many times. Still receiving this error: " name, abrev = line.replace("\n","").split(",")
ValueError: too many values to unpack" There is only one comma per line, as shown in my screenshot of the text file above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68155/discussion-between-snickers3192-and-philip-mcquitty).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
longSubjectNames = [] #example: "Academy for Classical Acting"
abbreviations = [] #example: "ACA"

with open ("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.txt", "r") as myfile:

    for line in myfile:
        allSubsAndAbrevs = line.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "").split(",")
        longSubjectNames.append(allSubsAndAbrevs[0])
        abbreviations.append(allSubsAndAbrevs[1])
```

Comment: This is only appending the first element in the text file and not looping through each line of the file. In other words, "longSubjectNames" is only appending "Academy for Classical Acting"

Comment: Do you have newlines between every line?

Comment: No, there is not a blank line between each line if that is what you're wondering. Have you tried printing the lists with your code above? Its only appending the first line, which is the issue I was having.

Answer (score -1):

None of the answers seemed to do what I was going for. Here is a working solution I came up with:

```
import csv 

myfile = open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/classAbrevs.csv", "rU")

lines = [tuple(row) for row in csv.reader(myfile)]

longSubjectNames = [] 
abbreviations = [] 

for item in lines:
    longSubjectNames.append(item[0])
    abbreviations.append(item[1])
```